# Fancy Arduino IDE

Tags: programming, ide

Do you know an IDE that is Arduino compatible, with:

- Black background; white hurts my eyes.
- Some auto completion features maybe?
- And also one that lets you minimise brackets. Xcode like.
- A better console...
- Something to clear the serial console.
- A **breadboard view**.

Something fancy!

Comment: You can use any IDE you want; anything fancy as you describe should have a way to define your own build system, so you can just use the makefile or scons or ino or your own shell script. As for the serial console, you will probably just have to deal with it not being built in to a single, monolithic IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Fritzing. I don't know how much you can customize there, but it has a whole suite where you can design hardware, write code, and even order PCB if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Eclipse can do everything you mentioned except for showing hardware layouts. The appearance of editor windows is customizable. If, by minimizing brackets, you mean collapsing them ("just indicate that something is here; I don't want to see the content"), Eclipse does that too. You can clear the console, but I don't know what "better" features you mean so I can't answer that part. It can take some setting up to get it working for you but it's far and away more powerful and feature-filled than the basic Arduino IDE. It is probably the most used IDE by people who look to upgrade from the basic one.

Update:
While it doesn't directly show hardware layouts, it does know about opening files with their default applications. If you put a Fritzing file in your project folder, when you click on it, Eclipse will launch Fritzing. If you put an image file such as a screenshot of the board layout, it will even open that within the IDE.